# How to write ShortestPath cypher in neo4j for the Game of Thrones Dataset

Tags: neo4j

For each person, write a cypher query to list the person’s name together with the max and average of the lengths of all shortest paths from the person in question to any other person. List the result in the descending order of the average length.

I can write it for two singular characters such as

```
MATCH (tyrion:Person {name: "Tyrion"}), (drogo:Person {name: "Drogo"})
MATCH p=shortestPath((tyrion)-[INTERACTS*]-(drogo))
RETURN DISTINCT length(p), drogo.name as Name
```

But am having difficulty doing it for all and displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Without a starting node to query, it will do a database scan with all combinations of all characters in your dataset. If there are 2k characters in Game of Thrones then you are doing 4,000,000 (2k x 2k ) combinations.  Doing this will cause your query to hang and will not complete. You should start with given characters then work your way up.

```
WITH ['Tyrion Lannister', 'Arya Stark'] as characters
MATCH (n1:Person ) WHERE n1.name in characters 
WITH n1
MATCH (n2:Person) where n2.name <> n1.name
MATCH p=shortestPath((n1)-[ :INTERACTS*]-(n2))
RETURN DISTINCT length(p) as len, n1.name as Name1, n2.name as Name2 ORDER by len DESC, Name1, Name2

Example:
╒═════╤══════════════════╤════════════════════════╕
│"len"│"Name1"           │"Name2"                 │
╞═════╪══════════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│14   │"Arya Stark"      │"Mathis Rowan"          │
├─────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│14   │"Arya Stark"      │"Myles Mooton"          │
├─────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│14   │"Arya Stark"      │"Rhonda Rowan"          │

....
├─────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│6    │"Tyrion Lannister"│"Dacey Mormont"         │
├─────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│6    │"Tyrion Lannister"│"Dagos Manwoody"        │
├─────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│6    │"Tyrion Lannister"│"Dalla"                 │
└─────┴──────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```